# Python Selenium using loop to check keywords

Tags: python, selenium, loops

```
keywords = ['no stock','out of stock','not available']

n = 0
while True:
    n+=1
    print(f'now check {n} times')

    for keyword in keywords:
        if keyword in driver.page_source:
            print(f'found {keyword}, refresh after 30 seconds')
            time.sleep(30)
            driver.get(url)
        else:
            print(f'could not find any of keyword')
            break
```

Hi guys, hope you are doing well.

I am trying to use selenium and to check whether an item is available in a webpage. My idea is to put all keywords related to no stock in a list and loop every 30 seconds to check.

however, if I put a break on it, the code only scan the 1st item in list. Is there any way that to break the loop if all the three keywords are not in website?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe is this the logic you are looking for?

```
keywords = ['no stock','out of stock','not available']

n = 0
while True:
    n+=1
    print(f'now check {n} times')
    keywords_found = 0
    for keyword in keywords:
        if keyword in driver.page_source:
            keywords_found += 1
            print(f'found {keyword}, {keywords_found} of {len(keywords)}')
    if keywords_found == len(keywords):
        print(f"We found the {len(keywords)} items of the list intot he page, so sleep and navigate")
        time.sleep(30)
        driver.get(url)
    else:
        print(f'could not the {len(keywords)} keywords, break')
        break
```